# Make a rhombus image with border and padding

Tags: css, wordpress, css-shapes, elementor

I would like to make an rhombus shaped image, with border and padding.
I've managed to make the image in a rhombus shape, but haven't succeeded in making a border with padding around it.

I'm using elementor builder and looking for a solution that will not envolve js coding, only css. is there a way??

this is what I'm trying to achieve:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05VXv.png)

Comment: Use a square an rotate it 45 degrees...much simpler

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I don't have a code cause I'm using elementor page builder.

Comment: Paulie_D, the thing is, the container get distorted when I do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea with one element:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 60px;
  /* this is your border*/
  outline: 2px solid;
  outline-offset: 15px;
  /**/
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 141%;
  height: 141%;
  flex-shrink:0;
  background: center/cover;
  background-image: inherit;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1003/800/800.jpg)"></div>

<div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg)"></div>
```

Comment: almost there! the bg image wont rotate :(

Comment: @ברגבאי what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clip-path` property to set the border for your rhombus image.

Here is the snippet link: https://jsfiddle.net/nk8f5pyg/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="rhombus-parent">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="rhombus">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rhombus{
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.rhombus-parent {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  background: red;
  width: 320px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

**Parent Div:**

1. First, you have to wrap the image in a parent div
2. That parent div will act as a border for our image
3. Increase the parent div width and height slightly higher than image element's width and height to resemble like a border

**Image tag:**

1. Update the image tag's position to relative so that we can reposition the element
2. Aligned the image center to the parent using `left` and `top` properties

**Can I use:** https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

**Additional useful link:**

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know, thank you for the help

Comment: what I see here, is that you added background color to the parent div .. but I need that the background color will be transparent and will have a black border. see the image I attached.

Comment: Add one `div` to element `div.rhombus-parent` and apply black color for the grandparent `div` of the `img` tag and for parent div apply same color as your theme's background color it will look as you expected.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to do that using elementor?

Comment: Yes, it's possible in elementor theme. Just a bunch of CSS applying to div tags.